# Order of rules in .htaccess file

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have an .htaccess file like this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^foo.*$ /cgi/foo.cgi [L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ /cgi/fallback.cgi [L]
```

but when I go to a URL starting with foo in that folder, the browser still gets redirected to the `fallback.cgi` script. If I remove the second rule, the 'foo' line works OK.

According to my understanding, the first rule should take precedence, and the [L] should prevent any other rules from happening.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are right, the 1st rule should be applied first and I think it is. The problem might be the 2nd rule is also being applied, so the code should be like this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^foo.*$ /cgi/foo.cgi [L,NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/cgi/(foo|fallback)\.cgi [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/foo [NC]
RewriteRule ^.*$ /cgi/fallback.cgi  [L]
```

Comment: If the second rule is being applied, what's the point of the [L] flag?

Comment: The [L] flag doesn't stop the process. Check the [technical details](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/rewrite/tech.html)

Comment: Learned something new. That's definitely counter-intuitive about how they process rules and conditions. +1

Comment: @AbsoluteƵERØ It is, in fact. And that applies to each rule, but all rules are usually processed anyway.

Comment: What are you seeing on that page which contradicts this, from the flags documentation: "The [L] flag causes mod_rewrite to stop processing the rule set. In most contexts, this means that if the rule matches, no further rules will be processed."?

Comment: This: *".. and then initiates a new internal sub-request with the new URL. This restarts processing of the APIphases..."* in API Phases-2. And this: *"The rewriting engine loops through the ruleset rule by rule (RewriteRule directives) and when a particular rule matches..."* in Ruleset Processing.

Comment: And of course [this](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html): *"The RewriteRule directive is the real rewriting workhorse. The directive can occur more than once,with each instance defining a single rewrite rule. The order in which these rules are defined is important - this is the order in which they will be applied at run-time."*, which indicates **all** rules are applied. There are exceptions, but this is not the case. But my question is: have you tried the code in the answer?

Comment: Aha! Thank you, I get it now. "initiates a new internal sub-request with the new URL" would mean it correctly hits on my foo.cgi, which *does* exist, but as it's no longer constrained by the -d -f conditions, it doesn't care whether it exists or not. I haven't tried it yet but I will, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The `^` means beginning of string.

```
RewriteRule ^foo.*$ /cgi/foo.cgi [L]
```

So that rules ONLY matches /foo followed by zero or more characters.

To match a file beginning with "foo" use this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule (^|/)foo.*$ /cgi/foo.cgi [L]
```

It matches:

```
/foo
/foo.php
/food.php
/foolish/dog
```

It does not match:

```
/kung-foo.cat
/FOO.php
```

**Update**
Remember that some browsers do redirect caching. I was testing this on my own server and had performed a redirect that was cached. Made me confused for a bit when my new rules weren't working.

Comment: Thanks for that but in this particular case I can assure you there's no case-sensitivity and there's no question that the path starts with 'foo'. As evidenced by the fact that it works as expected when the second of the two rules is removed.

Answer (score 1):

It is applying 2nd rule because;

1. In 2nd rule your are matching `.*` (means everything)
2. `RewriteCond` lines are only being applied to 1st rule only

Correct code would be:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# don't do anything for a file, dir or symlnk
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteRule (^|/)foo /cgi/foo.cgi [L,NC]

RewriteRule ^ /cgi/fallback.cgi [L]
```

Comment: "RewriteCond lines are only being applied to 1st rule only" -- I'm not getting that. Even if they're being applied to the first rule, then the first rule matches correctly and has an [L] flag, so the second rule should never fire.

Comment: 2nd rules fires after 1st rule has completed. Apache will keep applying all the rules as long as they are satisfying the conditions.